# Change Keras LSTM state during training

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, lstm

I am training Keras LSTM network .

I want to change the LSTM state from stateful to stateless and back to stateful during the training phase.

```
model_params=...
fit_params=...
for dataset in traindb:
    values=dataset.values
    train_x,train_y=...
    n_epoc=50
    batch_size=70
    if (model==None)
        model=create_model(model_params)
    history=model.fit(fit_params)
```

I want to reset the state of the network between each dataset and between each epoc.
I know the command `model.reset_states()`. How can I reset the network state between epochs?

Thanks,